# Como obtener el valor completo de una posicion en un numpy array

Tags: python, matrices, numpy

Es algo rebuscado pero intentare explicarlo, tengo una array que he creado apartir de una consulta de sql, este queda asi.

```
[['05-03-2021' '18:01:42']
 ['05-03-2021' '16:55:49']
 ['05-03-2021' '07:51:18']
 ['05-04-2021' '18:01:07']
 ['05-04-2021' '10:57:30']
 ['05-05-2021' '18:02:48']
 ['05-05-2021' '07:51:00']
 ['05-06-2021' '18:00:42']
 ['05-06-2021' '07:48:39']
 ['05-07-2021' '07:01:22']]
```

como ven en la fecha 05-03-2021 se repite 3 veces, pero yo necesito solo 2 que sea la que tenga la hora mas temprana y la hora mas tardia.

con el comando np.where() he encontrado los 3 puntos que son iguales a 05-03-2021

```
a = np.where(arr == '05-03-2021')
print(a)
(array([0, 1, 2]), array([0, 0, 0]))
```

me regresa ese valor, ahora este valor lo introduzco buscando los valores pero solo me regresa la fecha

```
['05-03-2021' '05-03-2021' '05-03-2021']
```

hay alguna manera de que regrese el valor completo? y como borrar el elemento que salio "perdedor"

```
    check = self.checadas(oper[0])
    arr = np.array(check)
    a = np.where(arr == '05-03-2021')
    print(arr[a])
```

este es el codigo que utilizo.
pero me he quedado corto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Consideraciones

Dado que hay fechas involucradas y la matriz requiere o está condicionada a filtros o máscaras entre sus columnas para obtener la consulta de interés, la matriz dada, se puede trabajar como un dataframe con `Pandas` para facilitar su implementación.

### DataFrame

Acá se crea una columna adicional que contenga la `fecha exacta` que es la fecha más la hora del día para obtener luego

```
la hora más temprana y la hora más tardía.
```

El código para armar el dataframe será:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

consulta = np.array(
[['05-03-2021', '18:01:42'],
 ['05-03-2021', '16:55:49'],
 ['05-03-2021', '07:51:18'],
 ['05-04-2021', '18:01:07'],
 ['05-04-2021', '10:57:30'],
 ['05-05-2021', '18:02:48'],
 ['05-05-2021', '07:51:00'],
 ['05-06-2021', '18:00:42'],
 ['05-06-2021', '07:48:39'],
 ['05-07-2021', '07:01:22']])

# se crea el dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(consulta, columns=['fecha', 'hora'])

# la columna fecha_exacta tiene el formato fecha para obtener la hora min y max
df['fecha_exacta'] = df.fecha + ' ' + df.hora
df['fecha_exacta'] = pd.to_datetime(df['fecha_exacta'], format='%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')

print(df)
'''
        fecha      hora        fecha_exacta
0  05-03-2021  18:01:42 2021-03-05 18:01:42
1  05-03-2021  16:55:49 2021-03-05 16:55:49
2  05-03-2021  07:51:18 2021-03-05 07:51:18
3  05-04-2021  18:01:07 2021-04-05 18:01:07
4  05-04-2021  10:57:30 2021-04-05 10:57:30
5  05-05-2021  18:02:48 2021-05-05 18:02:48
6  05-05-2021  07:51:00 2021-05-05 07:51:00
7  05-06-2021  18:00:42 2021-06-05 18:00:42
8  05-06-2021  07:48:39 2021-06-05 07:48:39
9  05-07-2021  07:01:22 2021-07-05 07:01:22
'''
```

### Consultas

Se crea un `df_2` que contenga sólo los datos correspondientes a `'05-03-2021'`

```
mascara_fecha = df.fecha == '05-03-2021'
df_2 = df[mascara_fecha]
print(df_2)
'''
        fecha      hora        fecha_exacta
0  05-03-2021  18:01:42 2021-03-05 18:01:42
1  05-03-2021  16:55:49 2021-03-05 16:55:49
2  05-03-2021  07:51:18 2021-03-05 07:51:18
'''
```

Se halla la hora más temprana y tardía correspondiente al `df_2`

```
mascara_min = (df_2['fecha_exacta'].min() == df_2['fecha_exacta'])
mascara_max = (df_2['fecha_exacta'].max() == df_2['fecha_exacta'])

# Se ordena por fecha_exacta aunque no es necesario
df_2 = df_2[ (mascara_min | mascara_max) ].sort_values(by="fecha_exacta")
print(df_2)
'''
        fecha      hora        fecha_exacta
2  05-03-2021  07:51:18 2021-03-05 07:51:18
0  05-03-2021  18:01:42 2021-03-05 18:01:42
'''
```

### Respuesta

Si se requiere el arreglo de la columna `hora`, con el método `values` se obtiene

```
df_2['hora'].values
# array(['07:51:18', '18:01:42'], dtype=object)
# Esto corresponde a la fecha '05-03-2021' -> df_2['fecha'].unique()
```

Comment: wow! realmente fue increible, me funciono a la perfeccion